# Silverlight Dispatcher locks up, stops processing tasks in queue

Tags: silverlight

Has anyone encountered this before? The Dispatcher sometimes gets into a state right after application start up that it stops processing its queue. The queue just builds and builds, and the Dispatcher does nothing. The UI thread is responsive. The best part is that the issue is non-deterministic. Sometimes it appears, sometimes it doesn't. It's much more likely to appear if I load a big file at startup. My app does a lot of things, and I don't know where to start debugging. Wish I could just examine the Dispatcher's code, but that's what you get when using a closed-source framework. Damn MS and damn buggy Silverlight.

Comment: Hi @Aleksandr did you ever get a workaround for this? Would really appreciate if you can share any solutions you might have got.

Comment: @SarafTalukder Well, I wrote some things in an answer. Did you notice it? Anyway, I don't remember the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but here is a free tool from Telerik that you can use to examine the code for the Dispatcher:
http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

You could also use Reflector, but it is not free (14 day trial):
http://www.reflector.net/

Comment: Great idea! Surprisingly, the Dispatcher code is very brief. But.. what is the best way to use the decompiled code with the debugger? I seem to remember one of the tools (maybe DotPeek) let you do that automatically, but I don't see the option in VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Reflector helped out debugging the Dispatcher (it generates PDB and integrates well). Looks like the Silverlight Dispatcher is just a thin wrapper for a native code dispatcher. The wrapper only handles queuing up BeginInvoke delegates and running them when the native dispatcher calls a callback on the Dispatcher. When the queue is empty and the first delegate is queued, Dispatcher alerts RuntimeHost that it should callback the Dispatcher whenever it gets the chance.

My theory on the bug (which definitely occurs when running Out-of-Browser, but not sure about in-Browser) is that if Dispatcher requests RuntimeHost to callback at the wrong time (eg, while application startup is not finished or when RuntimeHost is processing a lot of new UI elements... can't say exactly), the RuntimeHost forgets about the callback. Dispatcher never asks it a second time and never does any work.

A workaround may be to use DispatcherTimer (which seems bug-free...when Dispatcher gets stuck, my DispatcherTimers continue ticking). The easiest drop-in replacement for Dispatcher may be to copy the Dispatcher decompiled source code, which includes a DispatcherTimer-based codepath.